# solution for recurrence relation, characteristic roots method.

Tags: recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

For my characteristic roots method for solving a homogeneous recurrence relation, I got the roots for the equation as $2,2,3,3$.

for satisfying the boundary conditions, will the general solution be

$2^n(c_1+c_2\cdot n)+3^n(c_3+c_4\cdot n)$?

Please guide.

Comment: assuming a degree four recurrence with constant coefficients, the set of solutions for the homogeneous equation is a vector space of dimension 4; you have given 4 and they are linearly independent (over the field of constants), so those are it. But you should check by hand that each of the four really works....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks right - it would help clarity if you gave the actual recurrence you are working with - I assume it is $a_{n+4}=10a_{n+3}-37a_{n+2}+60a_{n+1}-36a_n$

Have you tried checking that your proposed solution works? Since four items determine the whole thing, you need the four coefficients, but since this is linear you could check $2^n, n2^n, 3^n$ and $n3^n$ separately.